# formatting email output in bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that sends a user an email when their AWS access keys are too old.

Right now the output looks like this:

```
Hello tdunphy, \n Your access key: AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q was created on Wed Feb  7 22:55:51 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days. \n Regards, \n Cloud Ops
```

I want the message to look like this:

```
Hello tdunphy,

 Your access key: AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q was created on Wed Feb  7 22:55:51 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days.

Regards,
Cloud Ops
```

This is the line that sets up the body of the message:

```
 MAIL_TXT1="Hello $user_name, \\n Your access key: $user_access_key1 was created on $date1 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days. \\n Regards, \\n Cloud Ops"
```

Why are the newlines not working in this example? How can I get this to work?

Comment: In order for the mail client to recognise newlines, you have to escape them, which you've done with `\\n`. When you run this bash will eliminate single backslash as a recognition of escape and leave you with `\n` which the mail client recognise as a newline character.  You can remove a single backslash and you should see the result you're looking for, but you'll see everything in single line in the email.

Comment: Thanks. This is what got me the formatting that I want: `MAIL_TXT1="Hello $user_name, \n\nYour access key: $user_access_key1 was created on $date1 and needs to be replaced.\nAll AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days.\n\nRegards,\nCloud Ops"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
template=$'Hello tdunphy, \n Your access key: AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q was created on Wed Feb  7 22:55:51 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days. \n Regards, \n Cloud Ops'
```

Then either `echo` works:

```
$ echo "$template"
Hello tdunphy, 
 Your access key: AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q was created on Wed Feb  7 22:55:51 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days. 
 Regards, 
 Cloud Ops
```

Or `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s" "$template"
 Your access key: AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q was created on Wed Feb  7 22:55:51 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced. All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days. 
 Regards, 
 Cloud Ops
```

With `printf` you can assemble the template fields more easily as well:

```
$ t2=$'Fields:\n\tf1=%s\n\tf2=%s'
$ printf "$t2" 101 102
Fields:
    f1=101
    f2=102
```